# Running time of std::list parallel quick sort

Tags: c++

I follow the quick sort implementation in Chapter 4 of 《C++ Concurrency in Action》,and then comparing the single-threaded and multi-threaded runtimes, the code is as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
  int num_elements = 10000;
    list<int> input(num_elements);
    // generate random numbers
    std::generate(input.begin(), input.end(),
                  []{ return std::rand();});

  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto sorted = sequential_quick_sort(input); // single-thread
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "sequence :" << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count() << endl;
  }

  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto sorted = parallel_quick_sort(input);   // multi-thread (two thread)
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "parallel :" << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sequence :15.1315
parallel :14.6983
```

Output shows that multi-thread has no better performance. But when I change the code as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
  int num_elements = 10000;

  {
      list<int> input(num_elements);
      // generate random numbers
      std::generate(input.begin(), input.end(),
                    []{ return std::rand();});

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto sorted = sequential_quick_sort(input); // single-thread
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "sequence :" << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count() << endl;
  }

  {
      list<int> input(num_elements);
      // generate random numbers
      std::generate(input.begin(), input.end(),
                    []{ return std::rand();});

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto sorted = parallel_quick_sort(input);   // multi-thread (two thread)
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "parallel :" << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sequence :15.0191
parallel :7.93202
```

Multi-thread version is twice as fast as the single-thread version. 
But why?

Comment: In the first version you're sorting the already sorted list, so it's possible that you're getting a worst-case scenario in a certain regard and the algorithm won't be able to exploit the parallelism. What happens if you re-shuffle the list?

Comment: then, i would also try to use a bigger list, parallelism with small tasks is often penalized by synchronization overhead

Comment: After re-shuffle the list, the running time is in line with expectations. But the input is copyed into the sequential_quick_sort(), so input is never be sorted when it passed into parallel_quick_sort()
This makes me very confused.